# How to change the value in an onClick with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click

I have a clicker game that I am developing and when I click the image at the start I have it set by default to be one click per click. I am wanting to make a button that forces the value of one click, to be two clicks per click. None of the solutions I have tried seem to work. Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
            <img src="rust.jpg" id="click" value="Click" />

        </div>

        <script src="picture.js"></script>

        <script src="clicks.js"></script>

        <script src="2clicks.js"></script>

            <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

            <button onClick="twoClicks()">Click Me</button>
```

Clicks.js:

```
var clicks = 0;
function onClick(x) {
    clicks += x;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

2clicks.js:

```
function twoClicks() {
    document.getElementById("onClick").innerHTML = onClick(2);
}
```

I want to click the button and make the img increase clicks by two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Might be making this to hard on your self

Why not have a `click` method and have it take an argument of it's multiplier.

For example if you need on click than do something like this

`click(1)`
and for two clicks do something like this `click(2)`

So for your game you could have code that looks like this in Javascript

```
function click(n){
   for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    addPoints()
   }
}
```

Or even just add points directly through from your `click` function.

All you would have to do for the different clicks would call them as such

```
<button id="clickOne" onClick="click(1)">Click Me</button>

<button id="clickTwo" onClick="click(2)">Click me for two</button>
```

And if you want these values to increase with outside influence you could even have a value for your multiplier. There is allot of ways to approach this and if you need more assistance let me know in the comments.

If you need to make the `clickOne` element do two clicks suddenly something you can do is reassign the `onclick` attribute like so.

```
document.getElementById('clickOne').onclick = function(){click(2)};
```

Comment: What I am trying to go for is for the button to make the img increase the clicks by two. I dont want the button to be the only things that increases the click count by two. I need onClick(1) in my img to turn to onClick(2) with the use of the button or something else.

Comment: I understand! What you can do is rebind the `onclick`. 

This should help.
`document.getElementById("img").onclick = onClick(2);`

Comment: Let me know if something like that works for you so I can update my answer.

Comment: in my 2clicks.js i set line 2 to "document.getElementById("div").onClick = onClick(2);" and then I added the id "div" to the <div>. When I start, it will do what I want it to do, by clicking by ones. Once I click the button, it activates this script and then my img wont increase by any clicks at all.

Comment: Change `document.getElementById("div").onClick` to `document.getElementById("div").onclick`

Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: found a solution, your line was missing a few things, this one worked, document.getElementById("div").onclick = function(){ onClick(2); } ;

Comment: Haha, nice job spotting it. I'll update my answer to make your working version!

Comment: @NateRice Fixed it up. Thanks!

Comment: thank you so much, been stuck on this for a while, so glad to get over it.

Answer (score 2):

Since onClick already handles the DOM manipulation, just try

```
function twoClicks() {
    onClick(2);
}
```

Comment: I need to change onClick(1) in my <p> to onClick(2) so that when ever I click the img it will increase my clicks by 2. I want the button not to be the plus 2, but to make the img become the plus two.

Answer (score 0):

u can do it by this way :

```html
 <button onClick="this.innerHtml = 'new value'">Click Me</button>
```